# What bonuses do you receive when attacking from high ground?

Tags: starcraft-2

**Question 1:**
What is the amount of damage increase if your forces are attacking from high ground?

**Question 2:**
Do "2 high ground levels" give any benefit compared to '1 high ground level'? Sometimes your base is on the high ground and it exits onto the natural (that is actually on the 'neutral' level). The exit from the natural leads to 'low ground'. So comparing high ground to 'low-ground' you have double level of difference. Does this give any additional benefits?

**Question 3:**
Does a Colossus receive a bonus when it is shooting from high-ground?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

High ground does not confer any attack bonus. It simply means you can shoot the enemy without them shooting back (unless they have an air unit or other means of "seeing" you up on the high ground.

Double-high ground does not confer any bonuses beyond high ground. The only difference (that I know of) is that jumping/climbing units like Reapers and Colossi cannot scale a double-high cliff - they have to climb one level at a time.

Comment: A better description would be: High Ground conveys the bonus Fog of War against non-flying units (minus Colossus).  Fog of War allows you to attack without retaliation.

Comment: @tzenes Well said. I simply meant having the high ground confers no +damage bonus.